# Fedora -- Pdftk File not found, snap installation

Tags: files, fedora, application, pdftk, snap

I am running Fedora 31 under KDE. I installed pdftk with the snap store. The installation process finished succesfully. However, when I am trying to execute a pdftk command (for instance here to burst the pdf "in.pdf"), I got an error so that the file is not found 
(I am executing the command in the directory where the file in.pdf is located).

What could be the cause ?

```
> $ pdftk in.pdf burst                                                              
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported yet, proceeding with partial confinement
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   in.pdf
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the kernel command-line option `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0`
If you are using [GRUB2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) as bootloader on `Fedora 31` you can add this option in `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` and then reinstall the bootloader and reboot:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg  
grub2-install /dev/sdX
```

For more info and caveats you can read [this](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/fedora-31-control-group-v2).